# Error 1064 <42000> on mysql when i'm trying to create table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
   `title` varchar(255) not null,
   `id` int(11) not null,
   `ph_path` varchar(255) not null,
   `description` varchar(255) not null,
   `privilange` varchar(20) not null,
   `owner` varchar(60) not null,
   `provoles` int(11),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=greek;
```

I'm getting `error 1064 <4200>` and I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: The trailing comma after your `PRIMARY KEY` looks mighty suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trailing comma in the primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), <--- remove that
```

The full error would read something like:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB

In MySQL, the position pointed to by the error message (`near ')ENGINE`) will show you the character immediately *after* where the error occurred.  Look to the previous thing in your statement and you'll find your syntax error.

Comment: @user1385257 Getting what error? What exact full error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to remove the comma after `` PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ``.